# How to choose which properties EditorFor displays on Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I do `Html.EditorFor(c => Model)` which walks through all properties and creates input elements in form.

But I need something like `Bind(Include="Name")` with which I like to learn which elements `EditorFor` will actually create for me as I don't need `ID` and `ModifiedSince` kind of properties to be filled out by users.

I know probably I will need to use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` maybe but it seems MVC community is lacking documentation compared to Web Forms.

Long story short, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int ID { get; set; }

[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public DateTime ModifiedSince { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

anotate the property with `[HiddenField(DisplayValue=false)]`

```
[HiddenField(DisplayValue=false)]
public int Id {get; set;}
```

Comment: What you're doing here to declare the fields as HiddenField and hide their values? But still they will be shown as `<input type='hidden' value=''/>` right?